# Ajax Returning a view but it is not showing using mvc4

Tags: .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

**csHtml code**

1st Foreach loop is create dynamic menu of Food categories list.
2nd Foreach loop is showing products onclick dynamic menu.

```
@foreach (var i in Model.Foods)
{                                       
<a href="#" id="@i.FoodList" class="@i.FoodList" onclick="test(this.id)" >@i.FoodList</a>
}

@foreach (var j in Model.Products)
{
<div class="card col-lg-2">
   <a href="../Home/ProductDetails">
      <img src="~/Images/@j.Images" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
           <p class="card-text ProName">@j.Product_Name</p>
           <p class="card-text ProOrder">Min. Order : @j.Min_Order</p>
        </div>
  </a>
</div>
}
```

**Script**

In this script i take a value of dynamic menu and send to the controller.

```
function test(ids) {
        document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
        var x = ids;
        alert(ids + "---" + x)

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            //url: "/Home/ProductList",
            url: '@Url.Action("ProductList")',
            dataType: 'html',
            UpdateTargetId: 'loads',
            data: {
                Id: x,
            },
            success: function (status) {
                console.log('Send');
                //$("#loads").load(" #loads");
                $("#loads").empty();
                $("#loads").html(status);
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log('something went wrong - debug it!');
            }
        });
}
```

**Controller**

```
        public ActionResult ProductList(string Id)
        {
            DemoProjectEntities DPE = new DemoProjectEntities();
            var data = new MasterDetails
            {
                Products = DPE.Products.Where(a => a.Category == Id).ToList(),
                Foods = DPE.Foods.ToList()
            };
            return View(data);
        }
```

So let me know what is problem in this case??

Comment: How large is ProductList (for all food)? Do you want to load all of them in the beginning (which you are doing with your controller) or call to get the ProductList on Food is selected (which is also something you are doing with JS)?

Comment: Yes when food is selected then show all Products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Script

```
    function test(ids) {
        document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
        var x = ids;
        //alert(ids + "---" + x)


        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("ProductList1")',
            dataType: 'html',
            UpdateTargetId: 'loads',
            data: {
                Id: x,
            },
            success: function (status) {
                console.log('Send');
                $("#loads").html(status);
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log('something went wrong - debug it!');
            }
        });
    }
```

Controller

```
        public ActionResult ProductList()
        {
            DemoProjectEntities DPE = new DemoProjectEntities();
            var data = new MasterDetails
            {
                Foods = DPE.Foods.ToList(),
                //Products = DPE.Products.Where(a => a.Category == Id).ToList()
            };
            return View(data);
        }

        
        public string ProductList1(string Id)
        {
            DemoProjectEntities DPE = new DemoProjectEntities();
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
            var Products = DPE.Products.Where(a => a.Category == Id).ToList();
            foreach (var j in Products)
            {
                s.Append("<div class='card'>");
                s.Append("<a href='../Home/ProductDetails' id=" + j.Product_Name + " onclick='getProName(this.id)'>");
                s.Append("<img src='/Images/" + j.Images + "' class='card-img-top' alt='...'/>");
                s.Append("<div class='card-body'>");
                s.Append(string.Format("<p class='card-text ProName'>{0}</p>", j.Product_Name));
                s.Append(string.Format("<p class='card-text ProOrder'>Min. Order : {0}</p>", j.Min_Order));
                s.Append("</div>");
                s.Append("</a>");
                s.Append("</div>");
            }
            return s.ToString();
        }
```